# How can I add a label that shows how many champions I own?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I've been stuck on adding a label for how many characters I own. For example, i would click the gold button 20 times. Now, i have 20 gold, since i have 20 gold i can spend that 20 gold to buy a character. Now i own 1 character, i want a label to appear where it shows how many characters i own. For the previous example, a label would appear and display "You own 1 character".

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Clicker {
    int first = 0;
    int second = 1;
    Clicker() {
        JButton button = new JButton ("gold");
        button.setBounds(0,0,100,40);

        JButton button1 = new JButton ("Gold mult");
        button1.setBounds(0,80,100,40);

        JButton button2 = new JButton ("Champion");
        button2.setBounds(0,140,100,40);

        final JLabel label = new JLabel ("First # "+ first);
        label.setBounds(110,0,200,40);

        final JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("Second # "+ second);
        label1.setBounds(110,80,100,40);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("clicker game");
        frame.add(button);
        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(button2);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(label1);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,500);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                first += second;
                label.setText("First #"+ first);
            }
        });

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(first > 2*second){
                    second++;
                    first-=2*second;
                    //first= first - (2*second);
                    label.setText("First #" + first);
                    label.setText("second # " + second);                       
                }
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (first>=20) {
                    if (second==2){
                        first++;   
                    }
                    first -= 20;
                    label.setText("first # " + first);
                    label1.setText("second # " + second);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Clicker();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is champion? What are three buttons supposed to do?

Comment: 1) *"Also, I want.."* SO works best when each thread is dedicated to a specific problem. Please decide which one you'd like to address in this thread, edit the other out, and start a new question thread for it. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Instead of using variable names like button1 button2, use names like "goldButton" , "firstLabel". Also, all Swing applications should run on EDT thread. Take a look at this ink : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your Clicker game. I recommand you to do some game design (images helps) before starting coding.

1. If you are using Eclipse-IDE there is a refactoring method where you can change the name of your variables and it will be propagated through your code.
   For label use : lblOfGold
   For button use : btnOfGold
2. Create your own customized JButton like ClickerButton extends JButton and put some properties and methods that are relevant to your game.
3. Create a Controller class that handle your game interaction and by accessing your ClickerButton you can do some action.
   I recommend you to register your Button in the controller and the controller will execute the action for you. Do not put your code inside the action listener for each button. This will increase the complexity and make the code unclear. Use  a new class for ActionListener. And register your buttons inside the controller. The controller will call your class ClickerActionListener and handle the action.
4. I recommend you to use Java-FX if you want to develop a Clicker Game. You can create a Scene and use also 3D models in your Scene and some nice Animations.

[image]

Sample code:

public class ClickerGame extends JFrame {

```
private static final String APPLICATION_TITLE = "Clicker Game (Kaisel)";

private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;
private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;

private static final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 100;
private static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 40;
private static final int LABEL_HEIGHT = 40;

private ClickerController controller;
private Map<String, ClickerLabel> mapOfLabels;
int first = 0;
int second = 1;

List<String> labelsName;
List<String> labelsKey;
List<String> buttonsName;
List<String> buttonsKey;
List<List<Integer>> boundsLabel;
List<List<Integer>> boundsButton;

ClickerGame() {
    controller = new ClickerController();
    mapOfLabels = new HashMap<>();
    loadResources();
}

private void loadResources() {
    labelsName = Arrays.asList("First # "+ first, "Second # "+ second);
    labelsKey = Arrays.asList("FirstKey", "SecondKey");
    buttonsName = Arrays.asList("Gold", "Gold mult", "Champion");
    buttonsKey = Arrays.asList("GoldKey", "GoldMultKey", "ChampionKey");
    boundsLabel = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(110,0,200,LABEL_HEIGHT),
            Arrays.asList(110,80,100,LABEL_HEIGHT) );
    boundsButton = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(0,0,BUTTON_WIDTH,BUTTON_HEIGHT),
            Arrays.asList(0,80,BUTTON_WIDTH,BUTTON_HEIGHT),
            Arrays.asList(0,140,BUTTON_WIDTH,BUTTON_HEIGHT) );
}

public void buildUI() {
    // variables
    int i;
    ClickerLabel label;
    ClickerButton button;
    // bounds rectangle
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    List<Integer> boundRectangle;

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    i = 0;
    for (String name : labelsName) {
        label = new ClickerLabel(name);
        boundRectangle = boundsLabel.get(i);
        x = boundRectangle.get(0);
        y = boundRectangle.get(1);
        width = boundRectangle.get(2);
        height = boundRectangle.get(3);
        label.setBounds( x, y, width, height );
        mapOfLabels.put(labelsKey.get(i),label);
        panel.add(label);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    for (String name : buttonsName) {
        button = new ClickerButton(name);
        button.setId(buttonsKey.get(i));
        controller.register(button);

        boundRectangle = boundsButton.get(i);
        x = boundRectangle.get(0);
        y = boundRectangle.get(1);
        width = boundRectangle.get(2);
        height = boundRectangle.get(3);
        button.setBounds( x, y, width, height );

        panel.add(button);
        i++;
    }

    this.add(panel);
}

public void launchApplication() {
    setTitle(APPLICATION_TITLE);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClickerGame game = new ClickerGame();
    game.buildUI();
    game.launchApplication();
}

private class ClickerButton extends JButton {
    private String buttonIdentification;
    ClickerButton(String parText) {
        super(parText);
    }
    public String getId() {
        return buttonIdentification;
    }
    public void setId(String btnId) {
        this.buttonIdentification = btnId;
    }
}

private class ClickerLabel extends JLabel {
    private String identification;
    ClickerLabel(String parText) {
        super(parText);
    }
    public String getId() {
        return identification;
    }
    public void setId(String btnId) {
        this.identification = btnId;
    }
}

private class ClickerActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private ClickerController controller;
    ClickerActionListener(ClickerController parController) {
        controller = parController;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ClickerButton source = (ClickerButton) e.getSource();
        if (source != null) {
            controller.handle(source.getId());
        }
    }
}

private class ClickerController {
    ClickerActionListener listener;
    ClickerController() {
        listener = new ClickerActionListener(this);
    }
    public boolean register(ClickerButton parButton) {
        if (parButton != null) {
            parButton.addActionListener(listener);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void handle(String parId) {
        if (parId.equals("GoldKey")) {
            controller.handlingGold();
        } else if (parId.equals("GoldMultKey")) {
            controller.handlingGoldMult();
        } else if (parId.equals("ChampionKey")) {
            controller.handlingChampion();
        }
    }

    private void handlingGold() {
        ClickerLabel lblFirst = mapOfLabels.get("FirstKey");
        // TODO document in here what this code is doing..
        first += second;
        lblFirst.setText("First #"+ first);
    }

    private void handlingGoldMult() {
        ClickerLabel lblFirst = mapOfLabels.get("FirstKey");
        ClickerLabel lblSecond = mapOfLabels.get("SecondKey");
        // TODO document in here what this code is doing..
        if(first > 2*second){
            second++;
            first-=2*second;
            //first= first - (2*second);
            lblFirst.setText("First #" + first);
            lblSecond.setText("second # " + second);                       
        }
    }

    private void handlingChampion() {
        ClickerLabel lblFirst = mapOfLabels.get("FirstKey");
        ClickerLabel lblSecond = mapOfLabels.get("SecondKey");
        // TODO document in here what this code is doing..
        if (first>=20) {
            if (second==2){
                first++;   
            }
            first -= 20;
            lblFirst.setText("first # " + first);
            lblSecond.setText("second # " + second);
        }
    }
}
```

}